# change an element in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have data in the form of

```
data = [
    {
        "date":"2018-05-18T-6:00:00.000Z",
        "something":"something1",
        "something":"something1"
    },
    {
       "date":"2018-05-19T-6:00:00.000Z",
       "something":"something2",
       "something":"something2"
    }
]
```

How do I grab the first element in the objects, edit them, then replace them back in the object?

So it should look like this

```
 data = [
    {
        "date":"2018-05-18",
        "something":"something1",
        "something":"something1"
    }
    {
        "date":"2018-05-19",
        "something":"something2",
        "something":"something2"
    }
]
```

I have tried something like this

```
var date = [];
const getSessions = () => {
 loginService.getUser().then((response) => {
  var user_id = response.data.id;
  console.log("getUser returning this => ", response.data);
  loginService.getUserSessions(user_id).then((response) => {
    $scope.sessions = response.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.sessions.length; i++){
      date.push($scope.sessions[i].next_class.slice(0,10));
  };

  $scope.sessions.push(date);
  console.log($scope.sessions);
```

This gets the date shortened but doesn't replace the original date in the object.

Comment: `data.forEach(e => e.date = e.date.substring(0, 10));`

Comment: data is an array.. first access array elements.

like data[0], data[1]... now these elemets are objects literals, you can access them with key.. 

for first you can try data[0]["date"] or data[0].date

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like -

```js
var data = [
      {
      "date":"2018-05-18T-6:00:00.000Z",
      "something":"something1",
      },
      {
      "date":"2018-05-19T-6:00:00.000Z",
      "something":"something2"
      }
    ]

     data.forEach((record) => {
         record.date = record.date.split("T")[0]
     })

    console.log(data);
```

Comment: Does map run faster than a for-each and is there a benefit for creating a new array rather than modifying the current array as requested?

Comment: Your answer works, but using substring would be faster. No need to create another array using split

Comment: Yes, OP can have custom logic there. I added snippet just for illustration.

Comment: I hope my answer was not down voted for use of `split()`, OP's question was around updating an object element within an array and solution for that matters. Logic within forEach can be changed as per requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this also.

`

```
newArray = data.map(obj => {
    dateIntoString = moment(obj.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    obj.date = dateIntoString;
    return obj;
});
```

`